# Building transformation matrix for solving recurrence relation of two series with matrix exponentiation

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations

Could you help to find a way to build a transformation matrix for the recurrence relation

$$
x_n = \begin{cases} x_{n-2} + y_{n-2} + y_{n-3}, & \mbox{if } n\ \geq 0 \\ 1 & \mbox{if } n \lt 0 \end{cases}\\
y_n = \begin{cases} y_{n-1} + x_{n-2} + y_{n-3}, & \mbox{if } n\ \geq 0 \\ 1 & \mbox{if } n \lt 0 \end{cases}
$$

My first attempt was successful for simpler recurrence, but I didn't manage to find a generic approach:

$$
V_n = \begin{pmatrix} x_n \\ y_n \end{pmatrix} => V_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix} x_{n+1} \\ y_{n+1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5x_n - 3y_n \\ 4x_n - 2y_n \end{pmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 -3 \\ 4 -2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_n \\ y_n \end{pmatrix}
\\
A = \begin{bmatrix} 5 -3 \\ 4 -2 \end{bmatrix}
\\
V_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\\
V_n = A^nV_0
$$

Here is good explanation, but not for two series: [http://www.math.cmu.edu/~mradclif/teaching/228F16/recurrences.pdf](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Emradclif/teaching/228F16/recurrences.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a little icky, but here you can represent this recurrence with the following $5 \times 5$ transformation matrix:
$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then all your equations (except the initial conditions) are expressed in the equation
$$M \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_{n - 1} \\ x_{n - 2} \\ y_{n - 1} \\ y_{n - 2} \\ y_{n - 3}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_n \\ x_{n - 1} \\ y_{n} \\ y_{n - 1} \\ y_{n - 2}\end{bmatrix}$$
You can then proceed to perform matrix exponentiation on $M$ and apply the matrix on the initial condition vector
$$\vec{v}_0 = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_0 \\ y_2 \\ y_1 \\ y_0\end{bmatrix}$$
the appropriate number of times to find the general form of $x_n$ and $y_n$.

**EDIT:** How exactly do you construct this matrix?

The motivation behind using matrices to solve linear recurrences is to find a matrix $M$ such that $\vec{v}_n = M \vec{v}_{n - 1}$, where $\vec{v}_n$ contains the recursion's quantities of interest (here we are interested in solving for $x_n$ and $y_n$, so we want $\vec{v}_n$ to contain both of them. Doing so effectively solves the recurrence, because it follows that $\vec{v}_n = M^{n - 1} \vec{v}_0$ (or something like that with $M$ raised to a slightly different power, depending on what the vector of initial conditions $\vec{v}_0$ is), which is something we can calculate directly.

In a first-degree recurrence (e.g. all terms with subscript $n$ depend only on terms with subscript $n - 1$), we can just choose $\vec{v}_n$ to be the vector $\begin{bmatrix} x_n \\ y_n \end{bmatrix}$ and we can treat the recurrence conditions as a matrix equation. For example, if the first-degree recurrence we seek to solve is
$$\begin{cases} 
x_n = a x_{n-1} + b y_{n - 1} \\
y_n = c x_{n - 1} + d y_{n - 1} 
\end{cases}$$
then the corresponding matrix equation is
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_{n-1} \\ y_{n-1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_n \\ y_n \end{bmatrix}$$
Here you have a recurrence which is second-degree in $x_n$ and third-degree in $y_n$ (i.e. $x_n$ and $y_n$ depend on terms up till $x_{n - 2}$ and $y_{n -3}$), so our $\vec{v}_{n - 1}$ vector should include both $x_{n - 1}$ to $x_{n - 2}$ and should also include all terms from $y_{n - 1}$ to $y_{n - 3}$. So this mean $\vec{v}_n$ will contain both $x_n$ and $x_{n - 1}$, and $y_n$ thru $y_{n - 2}$.

To find the matrix, we just must find the matrix $M$ so that
$$M \vec{v}_{n - 1} = M \begin{bmatrix} x_{n - 1} \\ x_{n - 2} \\ y_{n - 1} \\ y_{n - 2} \\ y_{n - 3} \end{bmatrix} = \vec{v}_n = \begin{bmatrix} x_n \\ x_{n - 1} \\ y_{n} \\ y_{n - 1} \\ y_{n - 2}\end{bmatrix}$$
The second, fourth, and fifth row will be easy to fill out (because $x_{n - 1}, ~ y_{n - 1}, $ and $y_{n-2}$ are entries in both $\vec{v}_n$). The first and third row will be filled out according to the linear combination of the elements of $\vec{v}_{n-1}$ that determine them.

If you have even more sequences (e.g. if you added $z_n$), you just have to follow a similar procedure, by adding whichever terms $z_n$ depends on to the vector $\vec{v}_{n-1}$, and fill out the matrix $M$ accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you explain more detailed how did you come up with the M matrix here? My main goal is to be able to construct the transformation matrices for similar recurrences. I would really appreciate it if you explain or give some links to materials with a good explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @Furdarius Please see my edits.

Comment: It's great explanation! Thank you @paulinho!

So, we end up with

$$
\vec{v}_n=\begin{pmatrix} x_{n-1} \\ x_{n-2} \\ y_{n-1} \\ y_{n-2} \\ y_{n-3} \end{pmatrix} =>
\vec{v}_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix} x_{n} \\ x_{n-1} \\ y_{n} \\ y_{n-1} \\ y_{n-2} \end{pmatrix} =>
\vec{v}_0=\begin{pmatrix} x_{0-1} \\ x_{0-2} \\ y_{0-1} \\ y_{0-2} \\ y_{0-3} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_{0-1} \\ x_{0-2} \\ y_{0-1} \\ y_{0-2} \\ y_{0-3} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_{-1} \\ x_{-2} \\ y_{-1} \\ y_{-2} \\ y_{-3} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: And if continue to calculate, we end up with the correct result! Great!
$$
\vec{v}_n = M^n \cdot \vec{v}_0 => 


\vec{v}_5 = M^5 \cdot \vec{v}_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 5 & 5 & 4 & 5 \\ 2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 6 & 7 & 5 & 6 \\ 2 & 3 & 4 & 3 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 21 \\ 11 \\ 27 \\ 15 \\ 9 \end{pmatrix} => \begin{pmatrix} x_{5-1} = 21 \\ x_{5-2} = 11 \\ y_{5-1} = 27 \\ y_{5-2} = 15 \\ y_{5-3} = 9 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: And what if the recurrence extended with $n\cdot7^n$ and $n\cdot3^n$ to 
$$
x_n = \begin{cases} x_{n-2} + y_{n-2} + y_{n-3} + n\cdot7^n, & \mbox{if } n\ \geq 0 \\ 1 & \mbox{if } n \lt 0 \end{cases}\\
y_n = \begin{cases} y_{n-1} + x_{n-2} + y_{n-3} + n\cdot3^n, & \mbox{if } n\ \geq 0 \\ 1 & \mbox{if } n \lt 0 \end{cases}
$$

Could we separate the solution on two steps: calc for $x_{n-2} + y_{n-2} + y_{n-3}$ and calc for $n\cdot7^n$ and then sum results? Or it won't be correct?

Comment: @Furdarius You're exactly right. Unfortunately, for your last example, the recurrence is no longer linear, so the method doesn't apply as it is. I think there could definitely be ad-hoc ways to accommodate the changes, but I would definitely need to think. You can consider asking this follow-up in a new question!